# How do you call non RESTful resources?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In Rails (my API) we can define a `collection` route (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on a resource. Lets say I have a route that looks like `/users/summary`.

How do I call this endpoint in Ember?

Was looking at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html and don't see anything relevant.

At this point, I am guessing I would need to do `Ember.$.ajax`. Or is there a way to call the endpoint via Ember Data?

Comment: This depends on how you define the Models. Could you please show us the model definitions, and routes?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make this work by using [DS.RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) and [DS.RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html).

The adapter will make Ember Data call the correct endpoint for your `Model`. And the serializer will transpose the returned data into something compatible with Ember Data.